# How would I retrieve the 'value' from an HTML input element?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, element, screen-scraping

I am working on a project where I need the 'value' number of the HTML found below. The number changes every second I need to find a way to scrape this input element real time to retrieve the value. I am new to HTML and python so I do not know where to start. Is there a way to do this?

To clarify, I am working in python and a method that uses bs4 would be ideal. Thanks

```
<input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="72500">
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("price").value`

Comment: @AdamSmooch python has same syntax as javascript?

Comment: nope!  see the answer below for info on a python HTML parser

Answer (score 0):

The [`BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package is the standard approach to HTML content parsing and value extraction in Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
s = requests.get('https://www.your_url.com').text
val = soup(s, 'html.parser').select_one('input#price')['value']
```

Output:

```
'72500'
```

Comment: The 'value' changes every second. Is there a way in BeautifulSoup to parse the webpage itself and not hardcoded html?

Comment: @MatthewPatience You will have to send a [request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to the webpage and pass the HTML response to `soup`. Please see my recent edit, as I added an example of this